# Neo4j database size not adding up to the math

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How correct are the "Store Sizes" values when you run `:play sysinfo`?

According to the spec found [here](http://key-value-stories.blogspot.com/2015/02/neo4j-architecture.html) and [here](https://sgerogia.github.io/Disk-Capacity-Planning-for-Neo4J/):

> Relationship: 34 bytes
>
> Property: 41 bytes
>
> String Property: 128 bytes

I have a system where roughly 90% of the relationships (~20m) come from one type of relationship, in which all 3 properties are either ints or floats (no strings).

```
Single relationship: 34 bytes
Total: 0.68 GB

Single relationship with 3 properties: 34 + (41*3) = 157 bytes
Total w/ properties: 157 * 20,000,000 = 3.14 GB
```

Doing the math, the total for this one relationship type should be roughly 0.7 GB without properties (3 GB with), however the *Relationship Store* column under `:play sysinfo` is showing > 7 GB. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you specify your neo4j version as well as using EE or community and if EE with high-limit format enabled or not ?

Comment: 3.0.4 EE, with high-limit disabled

Comment: I believe the store size reported in Neo4j Browser also includes transaction log files: https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/performance/transaction-logs/